# Azure DevOps + Docker : 'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm a newbie in Azure DevOps and trying to build my first full pipeline, but I have issues when building the docker image.

A line from the Docker file make the pipeline fail, the one with apt-get !

Do you have any idea to fix this?

Here is the error I got (the log):

```
Step 11/25 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && dotnet dev-certs https;     dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -c Debug -o out src/${PROJECT};
 ---> Running in 29ada69fe569
'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The command 'cmd /S /C apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && dotnet dev-certs https;     dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -c Debug -o out src/${PROJECT};' returned a non-zero code: 1
'displayName:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'failOnStderr:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

Here is my pipeline file:

```
- script: |
    docker image build --no-cache --tag=registry.gitlab.com/iznogood/myproject/iznogood.myproject.httpapi:1.0.0 -f .\src\Iznogood.Myproject\Dockerfile .
    displayName: 'Build image'
    failOnStderr: true
```

And here is the Docker file:

```
### >>> GLOBALS
ARG ENVIRONMENT="Production"
ARG PROJECT="Iznogood.MyProject.HttpApi"
### <<<

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

### >>> IMPORTS
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PROJECT
### <<<

ARG NUGET_CACHE=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
ARG NUGET_FEED=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

# Copy sources
COPY src/ /app/src
ADD common.props /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && dotnet dev-certs https; \
    dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -c Debug -o out src/${PROJECT};

# Start a new image from aspnet runtime image
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS runtime

### >>> IMPORTS
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PROJECT
### <<<

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:80;https://+:443;https://+:44359" 
#ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:80"  
ENV PROJECT="${PROJECT}.dll"

# Make logs a volume for persistence
VOLUME /app/Logs

# App directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy our build from the previous stage in /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg libgdiplus libc6-dev

# Ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 44359

ENTRYPOINT dotnet ${PROJECT}
```

Comment: How's your issue going? Do you use appropriate OS image?

Answer (score 2):

Check the pipeline and verify the OS that you're running on. If it's a Windows image, `apt-get` isn't going to work. Change your pipeline to use a Linux machine.

Comment: This is the answer. I accidentally left it on `windows-latest` after adding the Docker build task.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a suffix to specify which machine you want ?

For debian buster: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.201-buster AS build

The tag as been founded in "Full Tag Listing" section:
[Docker Hub Repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-base-image-update)